# NPM Install with package.json exits during extract --> gunzTarPerm with no error message

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, package.json, npm-install

I have a strange issue with npm install. I am just running `npm install` within my project with a package.json in the same directory

Here's the relevant part of the package.json
http://pastebin.com/zgT6eRxC

Everythings seems to go ok until it's hits this part in the process

```
extract → gunzTarPerm
```

I ran `npm install --verbose` but it just gets to here and stops/exits without any error message or text. My node_modules is left incomplete.

I don't know if this is relevant but before this last line it's nuking a bunch of files

Example

```
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /<path>/node_modules/.staging/require-bede8d129b4b602814b0d94932a5f956
```

Software Versions:

```
NPM - 3.3.12
Node - 5.1.0
Ubuntu - 14.04.03
```

Does anyone have a clue on what's going on here. I can do npm install on my Arch Linux dev machine and everything install fine. I'm not sure what's missing with my Ubuntu installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering my own question. Was running this on a 512MB DigitalOcean Ubuntu Server. Turns out there was not enough memory to finish things up. I made a swap file and it finishes.

Here a link on how to make a swap file
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This is happening to me when I try to install Angular2's quickstart project. I'm using Windows and just hangs on that part, never stopping.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by installing it using `yarn global add @angular/cli`

If yarn is not installed then install it first https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my solution was updating node. Be aware of EC2 Ubuntu instances, even if you update with apt-get update, for some reason Node is in the 8.x version, updating it will let you npm install without problems.